# problem regarding the binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I try to solve the following problem:

> A desktop publisher has to prepare 50 color posters. Each print has a $\frac{1}{6}$ chance of failure (wrong color scheme). How many posters should he print if he wants the chance of printing less than 50 good posters to be at most $2\%$.

The book proposes 67 as a solution.

#### Progress so far

I guess I should be looking for a $n$ such that $$\sum_{i=0}^{49}\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i} \leq 0.02\qquad (p=\frac{5}{6})$$

But how do I solve this for $n$?

*(I've tried plotting this for different $n$, and 67 seems to be right, is it also possible to calculate this? The book covers approximation of the Binomial distribution with Poisson and Normal distributions)*

Comment: You could try to see if thinking of the problem in terms of the *negative binomial* helps you. Take a look here (for an obvious link that will not disappear any time soon): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Comment: The normal approximation should get us close/

Answer (score 1):

With the normal approximation the equation is

$P(X\leq 49)=\Phi\left(  \frac{49+0.5-\frac{5}{6}n}{\sqrt{n\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6}}}\right)\leq 0.02$

$\Phi(z)$ is the function of the standard normal distribution.

$=  \frac{49+0.5-\frac{5}{6}n}{\sqrt{n\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6}}}\leq \Phi^{-1} (0.02)$

$=  \frac{49+0.5-\frac{5}{6}n}{\sqrt{n\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6}}}\leq -2.054$

Now you can solve the equation for n. Then you have to proof, if the value for n satisfy your equation. If not, your increase the value for n by 1. Then you have to proof again.